# C: fread function returns 0

Tags: c, fread

```
...
rewind(ftmpname);
if (stat(tmpname, &st_file)==-1) 
    longjmp(Berror, (ETMPSTAT) );

tmpsize = st_file.st_size;
i = 0;

while (i<tmpsize)
{
    n = fread(buf, 1, (READ_CONST), ftmpname );     
    write_byte(farch, buf, n);
    i+=n;
}
...
```

`fread` always returns 0.  I don't know what's wrong. I do a rewind before, and it didn't help. Sorry for my English.

Comment: How are you opening ftmpname and what are you doing with it before getting to this code?

Comment: ftmpname = fopen(tmpname, "wb"); then i use function which accepts ftmpname and reads info from ftmpname twice;

Comment: Are you writing the file without closing and re-opening it? It sounds like you are, which might explain why it's not going very well. You must have the file open for reading in order to read, I guess that's obvious but it seems you're missing out on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what is wrong, you have to check for errors. Here is what a manual page says:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> fread()  and fwrite() return the number of items successfully read or written
>      (i.e., not the number of characters).  If an error occurs, or the end-of-file is
>      reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).
>
> fread() does not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and callers must use
>      feof(3)  and  ferror(3)  to  determine  which occurred.

So why don't you use those functions which tell you exactly what is wrong?

Comment: thanks, I'll try. And one more question: function stat() returns 0 but st_file.st_sizes = 0. Why? Did I do smth wrong?